# Tableau Calc field syntax - inches to feet

Tags: tableau-api

Can anybody help me with the tableau syntax to create a calculated field?  I have a list of height data in inches, I would like to convert that to feet and inches.
So for example, 72 inches translates to 6 feet.  73 to 6.08 feet(or rounded to 6.1).  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your current field is called height, then the calculation would be:

```
[height] / 12
```

To set default format (round to 1 decimal place), right click on the field and select Default Properties -> Number Format -> Number (Custom) -> 1 decimal place.

Review this documentation for getting started with calculated fields.
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_create.html

Comment: Thank you, I think I was trying to make it more complicated than it needed to be.